# how to lock the android programatically

Tags: android, locking

i want to lock the phone when i click the lock button.anybody please help with simple code.i tried with part of code from  API_Demos but it shows some error.

Comment: What error? tell them over here!

Comment: Error(361): java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid 10045 for policy #3
WARN/DeviceAdminAdd(128): Unable to retrieve device policy ComponentInfo{com.lock..}

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the Android's screen programmatically using the LockScreen class like so:

```
KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

Take a look at the LockScreen class [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/policies/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java;hb=HEAD).

Comment: already i tried the code which you mentioned.but there is no result and also no error.the log cat message is as follows

12-16 10:20:31.687: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(332): Shutting down VM
12-16 10:20:31.697: DEBUG/dalvikvm(332): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-16 10:20:31.817: INFO/AndroidRuntime(332): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-16 10:20:37.376: DEBUG/dalvikvm(125): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2660 objects / 175544 bytes in 101ms
12-16 10:20:53.036: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: i have used same code of yours and i got the security warning so i have given this permission in menifest file.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />. but now its not giving me any exception and not even showing the lock. do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @sajjoo i got same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
KeyguardManager mgr = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock lock = mgr.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
lock.reenableKeyguard();
```

will NOT lock the screen. It just enables the keyguard lock. When you run with

```
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

and press lock button on the device it will not lock the keyguard.
To lock the screen programatically you have to refer to [Device Admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) and use locknow() method to lock the device.

Answer (score 0):

@Bhupinder Kindly check the following link.

http://musicm122.blogspot.in/2011/10/locking-and-unlocking-android-phone.html

```
//Get the window from the context

   WindowManager wm = Context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

   //Unlock

   //http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()

   Window window = getWindow();  

   window.addFlags(wm.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  



   //Lock device

   DevicePolicyManager mDPM;

   mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.