# How to show the lockscreen after tapping a button and closing the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, lockscreen

Hello I have already looked at these two posts, however they dont do a single thing xD [how to lock the android programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447312/how-to-lock-the-android-programatically)
[Lock the android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically)

However the second link does give errors but i dont know what they are. Thanks all for looking :)